# How to get an image link for a png of my Google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using a bar chart from Google charts and want to add a link to my page for an image version of the chart.

I tried the following code:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
      document.getElementById('png').innerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">Printable version</a>';
    });
```

But this says: `chart.getImageURI is not a function`. How can I fix that?

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/js8o2nrL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using a *material* bar chart...

```
google.charts.Bar
packages: ['bar']
```

*material* charts **do not support** the `getImageURI` method.

instead, you can use a *classic* chart...

```
google.visualization.BarChart
packages: ['corechart']
```

with the following option...

```
theme: 'material'
```

for other options not supported by *material* charts,
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

-- **OR** --

---

if you want to use a *material* chart,
you can create the image manually, using --> `createObjectURL`
then draw the svg image on a canvas,
to get the png, use --> `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Vraag', '2019', '2020'],
      ['Zijn medewerkers op de hoogte van de algemene VGM instructies?', 5, 2],
      ['Zijn de voorgeschreven veiligheidsmaatregelen toegepast en worden deze nageleefd (LMRA)?', 1, 3],
      ['Is de werkplek zodanig afgezet dat veilig gewerkt kan worden en dat er geen gevaar is voor omstanders/passanten?', 1, 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Afwijkingen per vraag',
      },
      colors: ['#169183','#105f44'],
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
      var canvas;
      var domURL;
      var imageNode;
      var imageURI;
      var svgParent;

      // add svg namespace to chart
      svgParent = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
      svgParent.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

      // create image URI
      domURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
      imageNode = chart.getContainer().cloneNode(true);
      imageURI = domURL.createObjectURL(new Blob([svgParent.outerHTML], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}));
      image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', parseFloat(svgParent.getAttribute('width')));
        canvas.setAttribute('height', parseFloat(svgParent.getAttribute('height')));
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        document.getElementById('png').innerHTML = '<a href="' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png') + '">Printable version</a>';
      }
      image.src = imageURI;
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_material"></div>
<div id='png'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to create a PNG on the printable page instead of an SVG?